# How to get the Canvas as a Bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

My app consists of a View which would be updated continuously. To be simple, this is a remote desktop sharing app where I will be getting the entire screen when the share begins (originalBitmap) and dirty rectangles alone for future changes in the computer screen (otherBitmap and clipRectData represents the smaller dirty rectangle and the rectangle where it is to be placed).

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (currentStatus != status.INIT) {
        scaleAndPan(canvas);

        canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, mMatrix, null);


        Region.Op op = Region.Op.REPLACE;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (clipRectData != null) {
                canvas.clipRect(clipRectData, op);
            }
            op = Region.Op.UNION;
        }

        if (otherBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(otherBitmap, mMatrix, null);
        }

        canvas.restore()

        /***
        Need something to do here to update the contents of the originalBitmap with the contents of canvas. Preferably without going over to draw the canvas again. 
        ****/
        invalidate();


    } else {
        invalidate();
    }


}
```

I am calling `invalidate` from inside the onDraw() to keep the drawing in loop where the bitmaps and rects are updated through external thread.

This is working fine as long as there is data coming up. Once the data is not received, the canvas draws the `originalBitmap` which was first received. I know why this is happening. I want a way to update the originalBitmap as soon as the draw cycle completes.

I have tried getDrawingCache() - which always sends me only the first cached image.

I have tried to create a new canvas and pass a bitmap and call the draw method. That too returned a null image.

Is there any other way to go about this? I have no control over how the data is received (that is, no server side control). And I need to use GPU for rendering. Using lockCanvas() on the surfaceHolder works perfectly but that is not what I want.

If getting the data from canvas is not possible, is there a way to replace a particular rect of a bitmap? I have a larger originalBitmap and a smaller (300x300px) rectangle bitmap which has to be draw over the originalBitmap with positions given by  a rect.

Happy to give more info.

Thanks

Comment: do not call `invalidate` from `onDraw` method, call it as a result of any change in your data model

Comment: Will change that call to `invalidate` but still I need to be sure that I get the canvas updated to a bitmap. Is there any way for that?